# Subquery in BigQuery (JOIN on same Table)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I have a BigQuery table with this data

```
client      spent   balance  date
A           20      500      2022-01-01
A           10      490      2022-01-02
A           50      440      2022-01-03
B           200     1000     1995-07-09
B           300     700      1998-08-11
B           100     600      2002-04-17
C           2       100      2021-01-04
C           10      90       2021-06-06
C           70      20       2021-10-07
```

I need the latest balance of each client based on the date:

```
client  spent   balance  date
A       50      440      2022-01-03
B       100     600      2002-04-17
C       70      20       2021-10-07
```

`distinct` does not work like in sql and group on client does also not work because I need count, sum, etc. with the other columns when I use group.

For just one client I use:

```
SELECT balance FROM `table` WHERE client = "A" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1.
```

But how can I get this data for every client in just one statement.

I tried with `subselect`

```
SELECT client,
  (SELECT balance FROM ` table ` WHERE client = tb. client ORDER by date DESC limit 1) AS bal
FROM `table` AS tb;
```

and got the error:

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported
> unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an
> efficient JOIN.

I don’t know how to make a JOIN out of this subquery to make it work.

Hope you have an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below

```
select * from your_table
qualify 1 = row_number() over(partition by client order by date desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using row_number window function?

```
select client, spent, balance, date
from (
    select client, spent, balance, date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num -- adding row number, starting from latest date 
    from table
)
where row_num = 1 -- filter out only the latest date
```